# Convergence in $L^p$ of $f_x(y)=f(y-x)$

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Looking through practice problems to get ready for my exam, I found the following one which confuses me a bit:

> Let $1\le p<\infty$ and $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R})$. For $x\in\mathbb{R}$ let $f_x(y)=f(y-x)$. Show that $\lim_{x\to0}||f-f_x||_p=0$.

Here is what is confusing me: Do we take a fixed $y\in\mathbb{R}$ and then take $\lim_{x\to0}||f(y)-f_x(y)||_p=0$?

Comment: No, it's $$\lim_{x\to 0} \int \lvert f(y) - f(y-x)\rvert^p\,dy = 0.$$

Comment: Why? I thought $||f(y)-f_x(y)||_p:=(\int \lvert f(y) - f(y-x)\rvert^p\,dy)^{1/p}$ per definition.

Comment: Maybe I misinterpreted your "take a fixed $y\in\mathbb{R}$". $\lVert f(y) - f_x(y)\rVert_p$ did look suspicious in that context.

Comment: Continuous functions with compact support are dense in $L^p$. The question is obvious for such functions. I'll let you sort out the details.

Comment: Well, it's not at all obvious for me...

Comment: Hint: continuous and compact support automatically implies uniform continuity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be proved combining the following two facts:

1. Continuous functions with compact support in $\mathbb R$ are dense in $L^p(\mathbb R)$, for every $p\in [1,\infty)$.
2. Every continuous function $f$, which has compact support on $\mathbb R$, is uniformly continuous and hence
   $$
   \lim_{h\to 0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x+h)-f(x)|^p\,dx=0.
   $$